# Searching an array for values ending in certain characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

So Im looking for help for writing a simple function in javascript. What I am trying to do is create an array of 6 name and print only those ending in "ie" or "y".

Here is my code - any help is appreciated. It unfortunately never reaches the function :(

```
//An array of names
var nameList = new Array("Freddie", "Mary", "Thomas", "Suzie", "Terry", "Kevin");
//Prints names before searching
document.write(nameList);

function e_names(nameList) {

    for (var index = 0; index < arrayList.length; index++) {
        var name = arrayList[index];
        if (name == /\bie\b/ || name == /\by\b/)
        document.write("",name, " </ br>");
        index++;
    } //End of for loop
} //End if method
```

Comment: From where are you calling the function?

Comment: `\b` means word boundary. So your expression would test whether the strings contain `ie` or `y` as *single* words (if you would use them properly). I recommend to read the [MDN guide about regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)  to get a better idea of how regular expression are used (hint: don't *compare* them with the value to be tested).

Comment: `//End of for loop` --- curious, is this comment really helpful to you?

Comment: To test a string against a regular expression, call the latter’s [`test` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). P.S. it’s `<br>` or `<br />`, not `</ br>`

Comment: `index++;` twice in your code.

Comment: @zerkms I sometimes do it when I have a pretty deep nest. Usually refactoring gets rid of the need for the comment though

Comment: @jasonscript: "Usually refactoring gets rid of the need for the comment though" --- that's it. Why not create problems instead of solving them with captain-obvious-style comments? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > It unfortunately never reaches the function :(

In your code, you are defining a function but then never executing it.  Execute it like so:

```
e_names(namesList);
```

The loop has a bug:

```
for (var index = 0; index < arrayList.length; index++) {
```

`arrayList` is not defined, at least not in this code.  It could be a previously defined or global variable, but then why does the function take a parameter called `nameList`?  I think this is a simple typo.

```
if (name == /\bie\b/ || name == /\by\b/)
```

I am not sure what it means to **equal** a regular expression, but I would hazard a guess it won't do what you want.  I think you want the .test function such as:

```
if (/\bie\b/.test(name) || /\by\b/.test(name))
```

Your pattern includes `\b`, the word boundary both before **and** after the y or ie.  Therefore, it will only match strings that have i or ie as exact strings or with spaces around them.  They won't match `array` or `key` or `cookie`.  I think you meant to anchor them to end of string as suggested by @xdazz's answer.  He even OR'ed the two expressions together for you:

```
if (/(ie|y)$/.test(name))
```

Finally, you double-increment `index`:

```
index++;
```

This will only iterate over "Freddie", "Thomas", and "Terry" because you increment twice.  The `index++` at the end of the loop construct is sufficient.  Take this line out.

Altogether now:

```
//An array of names
var nameList = [ "Freddie", "Mary", "Thomas", "Suzie", "Terry", "Kevin" ];
//Prints names before searching
document.write(nameList);

function e_names(names) {
    for (var index = 0; index < names.length; index++) {
        var name = arrayList[index];
        if (/(ie|y)$/.test(name)) {
            document.write("",name, " </ br>");
        }
    } //End of for loop
} //End if method

e_names(nameList);
```

Note that I renamed the parameter so that it doesn't cause confusion with scoping and I also put curly braces around your if block.  I usually don't change other people's code style, but I felt it was needed in this case to make it clearer.

I also changed the array construction to use the literal notation.  Much debate has been had around the `new Array` constructor.  It's probably safe for this example, but if there is a single element or the array contents are dynamic, it gets confusing.  For example, what does `new Array(17)` mean?  It means create an array with 17 null references in it.  It does not create an array with the number 17 in it.  For that reason, my advice is to use the `[ ]` syntax.  For details, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer with a mention of array literals. It’s all important!

Comment: Brandon - Thank you so much, your explanation is extremely helpful! And I definitely did not mean to include the index++ twice and in the midst of changing my code several times forgot to change my naming scheme as well. Lastly..stupid me I didnt even notice I never even called the function!! Many thanks for the advice I will be checking out the link you left!! Thank you all for the help!

Comment: ["Freddie", "Mary", "Thomas", "Suzie", "Terry", "Kevin"].filter(/./.test, /(ie|y)$/).join(" <br />")

Comment: I like @dandavid's approach.  It's very consice.

Answer (score 6):

Use `/(ie|y)$/` ($ is used to match the end) to test it:

```
if (/(ie|y)$/.test(name))
```